# How To Add Sensor Information To A Database In Time Intervals?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have successfully created an app that displays the sensor information I need. For the past few weeks, I searched online for any tutorials for my situation but none were able to help. The SQLite tutorials I followed all made note taking apps but I need to collect data in time intervals.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to collect and store data at timed intervals then you will need to have a periodic repeating task to collect and store the data. SQLite doesn't run rather it is invoked to either retrieve or store data, so the task would then do the necessary and use SQLite to store the data.

You may wish to consider using :-

- a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)
- a [Scheduled Pool Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor)
- an [Alarm Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)
- a [Timer Task](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask) (fore runner of a Scheduled Pool Executor)